# TcpClient/NetworkStream read write simoultanously on same instance

Tags: c#, .net-core, tcpclient

I need to communicate with a piece of hardware that only accepts 1 TCP connection. But I cannot find any good example where the same `NetworkStream` is used for reading and writing simoultanously.

The [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream?view=netcore-3.1) says the following:

> Read and write operations can be performed simultaneously on an
> instance of the NetworkStream class without the need for
> synchronization. As long as there is one unique thread for the write
> operations and one unique thread for the read operations, there will
> be no cross-interference between read and write threads and no
> synchronization is required.

However, I am unable to find an example that shows how to use the same instance of a `NetworkStream` in different threads to read and write.

I am unsure whether I should:

- simply use the `NetworkStream` directly for reading with `myNetworkStream.ReadAsync()`, or use a `StreamReader`,
- simply use the `NetworkStream` directly for writing with `myNetworkStream.WriteAsync()`, or use a `StreamWriter`,
- directly start a new thread with a `while(true)` for reading upon instantiation of the `TcpClient`,
- keep a global reference to my `NetworkStream` instance so that I can write whenever...

I'm far from being an expert when it comes to TCP connections/network communication, so there are definitely things I don't fully understand...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Those are all things you may or may not choose to do. This isn't really a "one right way to do this" sort of situation.

Comment: Would you have an example of how to use the same NetworStream to read and write simoultanously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember with I/O bound tasks, [there is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

The paragraph you posted doesn't really deal with tasks, for example:

```
var client = new TcpClient();
await client.ConnectAsync("example.com", 80);
var stream = client.GetStream();

// start reading from the socket
var rBuf = new byte[2048];
var tRecv = stream.ReadAsync(rBuf, 0, rBuf.Length);

// send data and wait for it to complete
var sBuf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\n\r\n");
await stream.WriteAsync(sBuf, 0, sBuf.Length);

// now await for the data
var bytesRecv = await tRecv;

Console.WriteLine($"Received {bytesRecv} bytes");
```

There isn't two simultaneous threads doing something at the same time when dealing with the underlying stream.

What the paragraph is talking about is doing something like this:

```
var client = new TcpClient();
await client.ConnectAsync("example.com", 80);
var stream = client.GetStream();

new Thread(() =>
{
    var rBuf = new byte[2048];
    var bytesRecv = stream.Read(rBuf, 0, rBuf.Length);
    Console.WriteLine($"Received {bytesRecv} bytes");
}).Start();

Thread.Sleep(500); // ensure the above thread has started

new Thread(() =>
{
    var sBuf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\n\r\n");
    stream.Write(sBuf, 0, sBuf.Length);
}).Start();

Console.ReadKey(true);
```

In the above example, you have two distinct threads both doing something at the same time with the underlying stream and nothing "blows up".

As far as what pattern you should use... You have a few possibilities. You have first example above with tasks (modern approach), or you could do the threaded `while(true)` method using blocking calls ("old-school" approach). Or the `Begin...` and `End...` methods (between old-school and modern).

What's best? You choose. Personally I like having events fired off when data is available, so I tend to use the `BeginConnect`/`EndConnect`, `BeginReceive`/`EndReceive`, etc methods.

Sometimes though, I like to do a `while(true)` using `ReadAsync()` but using a `CancellationToken` to kill the loop.

I do *not* suggest using the `while(true)` with blocking calls. With having the wonderful tools that the TPL gives us, we shouldn't have to start generic threads anymore to accomplish anything.

Comment: That sounds good, I'm all up for not using threads, however, the piece of hardware I need to communicate with, might be sending data continuously, how can I ensure I have some sort of "process" that keeps receiving and raising events whenever data is received, while still being able to send something to it every now and again, all that without using a blocking while(true) in a different thread?

Comment: @Seb - you could start a `Task` that sits in a `while(true) { ReceiveAsync() }` and just fire an event when data is ready. Or use the `BeginReceive` method, which basically does the same thing.

Comment: A Task that sits in a while(true)? Not the other way around? A while(true) within a Task?